# Markdown in chat fails for multi-line messages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, chat

We've come to rename Markdown to Letdown in the [C++ chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/c-lounge) because it lets you down so often. I've now just found a pattern.

It seems markdown [fails for multi-line messages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/109192#109192). That is, this

> Letdown can't cope with multi-line comments.
> Let's see `code`?

fails to display `code` marked as code, while this works

> But `code` works.

Now, I think it would be Ok if you said chat messages shouldn't be multi-line. (Although I'd be a bit annoyed, because I like them.) But if so, please don't render them as multi-line (as is the case with comments), so we aren't tempted to use them.

Comment: @Jeff: This sucks big time, no matter which way I look at this.

Comment: @Jeff: I just asked had same question myself… could it be documented in the chat formatting help?

Comment: Should there be a userscript that fixes this on StackApps?

Comment: @aking: _What?_ How could a userscript "fix" the formatting built into the chat?

Comment: If you injected custom javascript in to the browser and parsed the dom to replace *this* with <i>this</i> for example.  I know people that inject custom js or css to modify the behaviour or appearance of many sites.

Answer (score -18, accepted):

It is basically assumed that if you have something that is multi-line, you're either pasting a block of text and submitting it, or you're posting a block of code and the whole thing is going to be fixed-font/code.

Markdown is only processed for single-line messages, unless the entire thing is code.

[Chat reference from Marc](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56880#56880)

Comment: That would be fine if it was obvious. Coming from SO, questions and answers fully support multi-line and comments don't support it at all. The chat seems to support multi-line messages, but silently fails to apply markdown. That's really the worst combination.

Comment: @sbi, Chat use markdown-mini.  It has the same limited markdown support that comments have.

Comment: I did get _that_. Still, the chat does _allow_ multi-line messages, which comments _forbid_. That's an important difference. It took us days to find out why it keeps failing unexpectedly in the chat. 
Also, I believe if I put multi-line into comments, while the line breaks get filtered, code stays `code`. (Yep, it does. This comment uses this.)

Comment: @sbi, I'm just passing along what Marc said. |:

Comment: I really appreciate the effort, but it sucks nonetheless. `:)`

Comment: So why not make it so that this 'block text' assumption is only made by chat posts that exceed the line length that a regular chat post should reasonably be (3-4 lines)?

Comment: So why don't they just fix it?

Comment: This should be fixed.

Comment: Sorry to say it bluntly, but this strikes me as a particularly dumb design decision. It's not even clear what the advantage should be; adding new-lines does not make a message more expensive to process but definitely easier to read.

Comment: This might make sense for Stack Overflow, but it's a nuisance for natural language sites, and other sites where coding is irrelevant.  It forces you to split formatted multi-line messages up, which, combined with the site's unnecessarily excessive throttling, makes for a rather frustrating user experience.

Comment: would like this to be not regarded as unfixable aka regarded as fixable. would like to be able to create something like custom oneboxes and multiline formatting would help with that. eg a link, followed by some description, etc, that can be quoted in other chat rooms. but also maybe not in conflict with other uses eg ASCII art or whatever. (but dont quite understand how those come out to monospace right now)

Comment: This is a strange feature - if you're posting a block of code then you indent it by four - otherwise it should be treated like normal text but with `<br />`s. I don't see why it should be treated so differently - just fork Minimarkdown for chat and make it support `<br />`s, special-casing messages where every line begins with `>` or four spaces as is currently done.

Answer (score 24):

I found a cool purpose for this, you can make ASCII art on multiple lines that ignores formatting, Here is a nice example,

```
.*..*.  /),/)   .*..*.  
"-.-"  ( ';' )  "-.-"  
.*..*. c(..c)   .*..*.  
"-.-"    OO     "-.-"
```

So with this feature, you can make bunnies and unicorns, ignoring formatting options.
Happy chatting!

**Edit:**
As requested, a unicorn.

````
\              M.   .M                                      
 \\         MM   M ~~~.M                                     
   \\\.    MM M        ~~. __                    .~~~~~    
     \\\``` M M         ..MMM                    M       M.  
       M.MMM   M . M         M         ----.   .M         M  
     ~.-   .M  M MM .MM  . MMM    MM.        M.M . M   M  M  
       MM  MM   MM .M .   M M MM              M .M.  M.  M   
               M    .MMM                       M     M  M.   
         0    .MM    MM. ,~~~                  ..   M   M    
             .M M       MM MM                  .M      .M.MM 
         M   M  M         MM                   .M    MM    M 
          \__  .M          M         M         .M.     .MM   
                M.                    .              M       
               MM       M             M              M       
              M  M     M          MMM  MM            M       
             M .M    MM -----.           ----- M  M        
            M M  MM                         M   M   M        
            MM   M                             .M  M         
            MMM  M                         M   M   M         
             M MM MM  .                   M   M    M         
              M M.  MM.0                   M  M   M          
               MMM.  .MM                   M. .M  MM         
                 . . 00                  M  MMM. M         
                                          00 M 00
````

Comment: It's of course important to be able to create unformatted multi-line messages in a programmer's chat. However, that doesn't mean _every_ multi-line message should be unformatted.

Comment: True, but since it was status-bydesign, I thought it would be important to highlight a purpose for the un-formated multi-line message.

Comment: I somewhat doubt that the main incentive for this "feature" was unicorns. `:)` I think, as Rebecca suggested, pasting code is a bit more likely to be the use case the creators had in mind when they designed this. Unfortunately they forgot the other use cases.

Comment: if it really is for formatting code and not performance(it's easier to get performance when if line longer than X, disregard rules) shouldn't there be a toggle button?

Comment: Yes, but you "ascii art" can't use bold fonts. If you are playing chess in chat you can't use bold for pointing out last move, for example.

Answer (score 12):

We now support multi-line quotes in chat, but the rest of markdown is still disabled for multi-line messages.

Comment: This is nice, thanks. Who do we have to bribe to enable the rest?

Comment: @Xeo The rest isn't going to happen. Doing full markdown parsing on long multiline messages can be costly and it opens up the path for trolls to be extra annoying. Chat isn't intended for posting long fully-formatted messages.

Comment: Trolls can already be very annoying even without that, and some users would like to format their multiline messages, so as not to be caught by the occasional message that slips in between two of their that should be displayed together. But oh well.

Comment: What types of quotes support multi-line formatting?

Comment: @Mateo What do you mean? Quotes as in "chat messages that are formatted as quotes in Markdown, starting with `>`".

Comment: so no formatting on multi-line quotes? http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1736701#1736701

Comment: @Mateo Correct. The only markdown that works on multiline messages is the quote itself. Everything else is still disabled.

Comment: @AdamLear - So, no multiline markdown is a form of automated chat moderation?  What's wrong with the existing moderator tools.  These just sound like excuses.  Is chat really not intended to allow me to post messages like [this attempt](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14135916#14135916)?  Pity.

Comment: @gilly3 To be honest, chat moderation tools are a bit lacking. I'd like to improve them at some point, but to be further honest... in the three or so years that I've been using chat, I haven't found lack of multiline markdown to be a major hindrance outside of being able to quote stuff which is now possible.

Comment: @AdamLear So I can't post pretty links in a new-line message but [screen-filling unicorns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136356/156248) are okay? This seems to be a non-solution for a non-problem. If you want to prevent screen-filling messages, just restrict the number of lines. Disabling Markdown does not do anything.

Comment: Why has this bug not been fixed in seven years?

Comment: @MikeWaters Because that's a feature. ([tag:status-bydesign])

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος No, it isn't. At best, it's a design decision not liked by those affected by it.