# Start chat rate limiting after the second message

Tags: feature-request, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Relax flood control in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74884/relax-flood-control-in-chat)

In many cases I need to post two messages into chat in quick succession - for example posting an image and then a comment to go with it so that the image is displayed in chat, or a image and a quote, or any other pairing of formatting options that require a whole post to actually display.

However, every time I do this, the second post gets caught by the rate limiter and I have to click again on retry to actually post the messages.

Could it be possible to have the rate limiter kick in if the user tries to post three or more messages in quick succession rather than two or more?