# Why do smartlinks in chat need their own line and "http://" to work?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Smartlinks are perhaps the greatest thing since sliced bread--IOW a pretty good invention that saves some time and makes life a little tastier--but they are a pain to use.  They need to go on their own line (a particular problem when combined with [overly aggressive flood control](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74884/relax-flood-control-in-chat)), and failing to include the http:// prefix causes them to not work.  Since I have not yet encountered an FTP XKCD comic, this all seems a bit unnecessary.

Is there any reason for these "features," and if not can they be fixed?

Comment: I wish people would stop complaining that they should be able to write novels in chat without anybody having a chance to interrupt. It's a *chat*, for goodness' sake, not a blog engine.

Comment: This is not a question about flood control.  That's addressed elsewhere.

Comment: The reason you give for wanting to onebox a link that doesn't appear as its own message (how would that even look?) *is* that it's "a problem when combined with overly aggressive flood control".

Comment: *A* reason not *the* reason.  Clarified in the question.

Comment: @balpha "How would that even look" is an interesting question.  Perhaps if not at the beginning or end of a message it could have the link replaced with the page's title, and if at the beginning or end it could get onebox'd as though the user had newlined it.