# Make the Chat rate-limit less restrictive

Tags: feature-request, chat, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I please be trusted to not to script a bot that dumps an endless stream of spam messages into the chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132483/can-i-please-be-trusted-to-not-to-script-a-bot-that-dumps-an-endless-stream-of-s)

Rate limiting isn't supposed to get in the way of normal use; it's supposed to limit vectors for abuse. As such, *most* rate limits on Stack Exchange are usually invisible.

There's one rate limit I hit almost *daily*. The freaking chat "*You can perform this action again in 1 seconds*" message.

Could we please just get *two* messages in there before that message? Or maybe make an exception for when one of them is a question/onebox link

It's hard to spam with two messages and if using a script it's easy to delay your spam 1 second. But it is *infuriating* to make a comment followed by a link to a question (so the link oneboxes). I do this *all the dang time* and hit the rate limit fairly often because of it.

Comment: This is so f'n annoying.