# Did the chat time limits get changed?

Tags: support, chat, rate-limiting

I've been travelling for a while, and haven't been in chat for a while. I came back today, and found that my previous typing speed of messages frequently results in rate limit errors, which I haven't run into for a very long time.

I'm a 25k+ user on StackOverflow, which is supposed to reduce the rate limits on some stuff at least.

Was any change made recently that could cause this?

Comment: it would be great ... if there is no time limit in chat  for 10k+ user ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm forgetting something, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167782/115866) is the only reasonably recent change in that area.

Comment: I'll accept the answer, but it still feels a bit off to me.