# Room owners should not be throttled in the Chat systems

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, throttling

I see a point in the throttling system, however for regular chat users and room owners it can become quite a nuisance.

The room owners already have no star limits for the rooms they own, would it make much sense to remove the message throttling for those users in their rooms as well? I know many other room owners, as well as myself, who would benefit from this.

So I'm opening this up as a feature request as well as a discussion, I would like to hear what other chat users think, as well as mods.

Comment: We're message throttled as well.

Comment: "You can moderate the site, but damn you if you want to post three messages quickly because you're a little happy on the enter key!"

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea - this can get really annoying. Especially since sometimes I come to the chat and see users abusing the system spamming with lolcats and whatnot - I move their messages to the trash and explain to them the room policy. While doing this I also keep talking to the regulars - this gets throttled quickly and it can be really annoying.

Comment: @rlemon: Room owners don't "moderate" anything.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132483/can-i-please-be-trusted-to-not-to-script-a-bot-that-dumps-an-endless-stream-of-s

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was making a joke towards BoltClock's comment, not my post.

Comment: Regardless of whether throttling should apply to room owners, I disagree with the statement that room owners don't moderate anything. There are plenty of times where I, as well as other room owners, will move inappropriate or spammy messages to the Recycle Bin or the Trash Bin. There's also the pinned messages, etc. They are (generally) trusted users, and I'm of the opinion that this trust should extend to throttling (or lack thereof). It's unlikely that a room owner will spam, and even if they do, other room owners will quickly squash it.

Comment: @rlemon: Yes, I understand.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at here? What's message throttling?

Comment: I don't recall ever being throttled in Chat.  Well, maybe once or twice, right after I posted a comment and then copy/pasted a link.  It said "you can retry this operation in 3 seconds (click here to retry)."  Much less irritating than "You can only do this thing once every 15 seconds; timer reset."

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't really for nor against what you want; but I will definitely vote on at least the time limit being upped, because it bugs me all the time when I'm "power-typing". I am not spamming, just having a lot of suggestions coming into my head quickly when discussing something.

It's always saying "You can do this action in 2 seconds".

This also happens when editing messages. You've spelled something wrong, so you *quickly* change it, then you spot another one... *quickly* change it. **OOPS** no, you can't do that, please wait. Gets quite annoying.

Answer (score -1):

-1, sorry. I dislike the throttling system as it stands today, but see no reason to disable it for room owners only. The principle of SO chat is that room owners are not masters, gods, or supreme beings, and are generally subject to the same rules as everybody else. *They do not "moderate" anything!*

The unlimited starring power is an arguably useful feature because it enables management of the starboard with notifications and the like, but I see nothing in the informal job description of a room owner that says they have any more right to spam the room than I do.

Comment: This is taking the position that room owners would be spamming. Spamming gets taken care of with the flag system already, the throttle is to avoid quick messages. Like mentioned in my Question, this gets triggered by some ENTER happy people when it probably shouldn't be.  I would also argue 10K+ users do not get throttled. The argument that we are not mods is fine, but I never mentioned anything about moderation and nor do I think the throttling has anything to do with it. So I'm a tad confused as per your point here?

Comment: The unlimited star for room owners is (afaik) not called out anywhere (maybe meta) and is less about moderation and more about freedom I would imagine (as the moderation part of that is being able to cancel stars and unpin messages which again, has nothing to do with this topic, I only used stars as a example of room owner privs that normal users do not get).

Comment: My point is that your proposal makes a clear distinction between the needs of room owners and the needs of _any_ chat participant, and this I cannot support. The throttle does need improving (dear god please!), but not like this.

Comment: If you agree with the problem, but not my solution, please suggest a solution that coincides with how you think it would be made fair. I suggested one thing for lack of a better option, and that was for trusted users to have it removed.

Comment: @rlemon: I did, [seven months ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167886/155739).