# Why didn’t formatting work in this chat message?

Tags: support, chat, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Markdown in chat fails for multi-line messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages)

I tried using multiple lines in [this chat message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1892601#1892601), but basic formatting, like inline code and a link, wasn’t applied. What rule did I break ;)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of not using multi-line chat messages! Formatting is [not supported](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=56880#56880) in messages spanning multiple lines.