# Chat FAQ is misleading regarding markdown in multi-line messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, markdown, chat-faq

This question follows the discussion in comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329516/196834).

We know that [Markdown in chat fails for multi-line messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages). Debatable, but OK.

However, the [Chat FAQ for formatting](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting) shows us what appears to be an example of a *multi-line message* with markdown formatting:

[image]

While the FAQ authors may have meant to show different single-line messages, this can come across as a single 5-line message.

That misleads some people (like myself) to assume they can use Markdown multi-line messages. The example should probably split up or the issue be otherwise better-clarified.

Comment: I recall there was another feature request to add styling to multiline messages

Comment: @iBug: That would be a different question... I just want the FAQ to be fixed for now.

Comment: Can't see any "example of a multi-line message with markdown formatting". Nothing is misleading.

Comment: @ShadowTheCurlyBracedWizard: There's a single example and it's multi-line. How can you not see it?

Comment: @ShadowTheCurlyBracedWizard The five lines that demonstrate formatting definitely *can be perceived* as a single, multi-line message. einpoklum As it's hard for some users to understand how it's possible to mis-interpret that, I'd recommend adding a screenshot and clearly explaining how it can come across that way.

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog: Done.

Comment: I also added some fudging to try and quell the downvotes. Generally, if you make statements of fact that don't resonate with others, it results in negative reception.

Comment: @Sonic for me it's obvious 5 different examples, but fair enough, if it confuse other people somehow it's a valid feature request.

Comment: Maybe that example is not especially misleading, but writing a multi-line message and seeing it not getting formatted is puzzling. Explaining why with a brief sentence in chat's FAQ would probably work better than [having to quote chat messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112526/410681)
("We support a limited subset of Markdown styling in chat, similar to comment formatting" is IMO not enough; multi-line comments are just converted to single-line, while markdown formatting is honored).