# Chat Markdown links don't work for multiline messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown in chat fails for multi-line messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages)

> Related, outdated: [Markdown in chat fails for multi-line messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages)

Whenever you post a chat message like this:

```
You ought to try
[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)
It is awesome
```

the markdown does not render. The reason is that "when you use multiline, it is assumed that you have copy-pasted code from elsewhere"(see related question).

Well, now we have a "fixed width" (`pre`) button for code, so that's no longer an issue.

Multiline posting is pretty useful in active chat rooms; it makes sure your message isn't split into bits.

Comment: Not outdated, and the "fixed font" button has always existed. Nothing changed here. It's very much by design that posting of long messages is discouraged.

Comment: @balpha: Hmm.... WHy are they discouraged?

Comment: Because it's chat, not a blog engine. The real-world equivalent of a screen-high chat message would be saying "shut up and listen to me for the next five minutes".

Comment: @balpha: Ahh, I see. OK then..