# RFC: Add Twitter-style hashtagging to chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, chat

The current way of entering tags in chat is not exactly intuitive, in my opinion.  I had to hunt through stuff to figure out how to do it the first time.

I'm thinking it would be better if chat supported Twitter-like syntax for "hashtags", and typing `#example` would get you a tag like [example](/questions/tagged/example).  Of course, this would only work outside of code sections.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

The `[tag:whatever]` syntax is also used in regular posts, mostly on meta to discuss various tag issues. The hashtag syntax looks like it would be problematic for the markdown parser as the header syntax is practically identical. And I would keep the syntax the same between the main sites and chat, anything else will just be more confusing.

As an example, typing `#example` at the beginning of a line results in

## example

Comment: +1 for using example as an example.

Comment: The syntax is *already different* between chat and posts.  We already have at least two different flavors of markdown.  In chat, multi-line stuff is mostly broken. [Intentionally.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70141/148873)  HTML is encoded.  And, notably, `#` doesn't work in chat.  If you're arguing for keeping chat and posts the same, i think that ship has sailed.