# Italicisation does not work with trailing period in chat

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown in chat fails for multi-line messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages)

When I write `_adj._` on a StackExchange post proper it gets italicised: *adj.*

When I do the same in chat, in a multi-line message, it does not: _adj._

Comment: I'm told this may be down to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages (which, by the way, seems quite ridiculous!)

Comment: Correct, Markdown does not get processed whatsoever in multi-line messages. It has to be a single line.

Comment: @animuson, maybe we should just fix it, no idea why they don't.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: According to the SE team, it's working as expected - there is nothing to fix.

Comment: @animuson, that's sad that they would expect it to not work right.  Sounds like maybe they're merging with Microsoft :)

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Their reasoning makes perfect sense to me. It seems much more likely that someone pasting a multi-line text is pasting code. Ergo, it makes sense not to run Markdown on multi-line messages. If you really think it's an issue, I'm sure they'd only be convinced by stats saying that multi-line messages are used less often for code, but then they might just say you're misusing multi-line messages. ;P Aside from that, pasting things from external sources which don't use Markdown also wouldn't make sense parsing them as Markdown.

Comment: @animuson, maybe they could come up with a solution that took care of both issues.