# Answers in chat without the nickname of the user of the original entry

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

We've just observed on [The Heap](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) the following:

[image]

That is, there is no mention of the author of the original post.  However, he got a notification about the answer and the arrow points to the correct entry.

Here is how to reproduce the thing: simply post an answer with a soft carriage return in it.  The new line must contain at least one non-whitespace character.

Well, I see this is a minor bug - but still a bug (buglet if there's anything like that :)

Credit goes to Andriy M who discovered it and Mikael Eriksson who showed how to reproduce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that is not a normal single-line message – Wikipedia oneboxes, YouTube videos, and, well, multi-line pastes – has no pretend-mention, since that wouldn't really make sense. The point of even allowing multiline messages is copy&pasting a text from somewhere, and adding a user name to the beginning of such a text is just wrong.

Using multiple lines for a normal chat message is heavily discouraged (to the [disdain of some people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages)).

Comment: Well, this discouragement is a bit misdirected, I feel :)  Newlines can give some structure to longish answers while keeping together it as a whole.