# Message reference visible when expanding a long multi-line response

Tags: bug, chat, reply

This issue appears to happen to any message that is

- multi-line,
- long,
- a response to another message,
- not (or not necessarily) formatted to use a fixed font,

like this one:

[image: collapsed message view]

Although the message is a response, it does not show the nickname of the person it is addressed at, and [I know that is fine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165996/answers-in-chat-without-the-nickname-of-the-user-of-the-original-entry). What does not seem fine to me is when I do this

[image: collapsed message view with marks]

to see the entire message, I get this:

[image: expanded message view with marks]

The bit added at the beginning looks very much like a chat message reference, which I am sure it is, except, as I understand, normally it is supposed to be invisible in the message display box, and this appears to be the only case when it shows up like that. By the way, the issue happens only in live chat, it [does not affect a transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/179?m=15179762#15179762).

So, in the end, I did not really have a problem with that, and even if I had, I am sure that would be a really, really minor problem. But I was wondering, maybe that little quirk would not be too difficult to fix?