# Markdown not always working in chat

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

I tried to post a [comment containing a URL and Bold Text](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15031631#15031631) in the [RenderFarm chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) and it didn't work:

[image]

However, I then tried to recreate the URL markdown problem using the exact same link, and also one with the same bold text, but they worked just fine.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages?rq=1) might be why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All markdown is [disabled on multi-line posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages). Make sure your post doesn't contain newlines.

Specifically, judging by the screenshot, there is a newline between *check...* and the smiley.