# Increase number of characters in Chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

I understand comments having a limit on the number of characters, but why must even chat messages have such a low limit? I suggest increasing the limit to twice the existing amount at least. Let us please discuss this issue here. I am open to all suggestions.

The current character limit is **500 characters**.

**Reason**: I regularly come across this limitation and it is annoying to break the sentence into two each time I want to post a specific message.

**Detailed Reason**: There are two types of chat, one is the regular site chat. Here the messages are typically small and do not exceed the limit. The second type of chat is when the discussions in a question are moved into chat for better use. Here the discussions get rather long and it is required to post lengthy messages. It is annoying that in this scenario (which happens quite a lot) one has to break up his messages to fit the limit.

For example, the sentence:

> @Unicorn1 you mentioned that "it is necessary to make all people follow the same uniform". However I believe that in order to make everyone follow the same dress code, it is required to follow the dress code ourselves. nobody likes it when the leader, himself does not follow his own advice. By simply imposing the rule that everyone should follow the dress code, but then not following it ourselves, we are setting the platform for unhappy followers. Because they will think "here we are being disciplined with dress code, while this guy chills in his jeans and t-shirt"

Is already over the limit. Now I can break this up into two and post it, but the flow is lost, because by the time I post the second half of the message, the user replies to the first half and the discussion moves in a different direction. This is especially painful when the discussion has more than three or four participants.

Comment: what is the current chars limit in chat?

Comment: You don't really say why you think you need more, only that you do. What situation has arisen where the current limit is too restrictive? It is unlikely to be changed 'just because', but if there is a specific *reason* the current limit is insufficient then that is a different matter.

Comment: Also, I see the length limitation as a reminder that chat should be short... they are more readable that way.

Comment: The limit is 500 characters, and it is short enough that I occasionally run into it. Just as a comparison, the current version of this question has 272 characters, 500 isn't all that much and you can easily hit that limit.

Comment: alright, everyone, I have added the reason and the limit. Thanks

Comment: @rene You can already dump large amounts of code or logs into chat. If you have multiple lines in your message (e.g. because you copy&pasted it from somewhere else), you get the "fixed width" option which doesn't have the 500 character limit.

Comment: People can converse in tweets. 500 characters is incredibly long compared to that.

Answer (score 7):

Gee, I don't think it's a problem. IMO the very word "chat" implies that your messages aren't university lecture notes. Use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. That way you can get multi-line messages. Note that [Markdown in chat fails for multi-line messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages) (i.e. it's never meant to work that way, IOW [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)).

I would also shift-enter twice so I'd get paragraphs, which look decent enough. For comparison, take a look at [this chat message of mine](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/24938?m=24479948#24479948) which is 8,364 characters. Chat has many crappy feature bugs/bug features but IMO this is not one of them.

Comment: How the hell is anyone supposed to figure out that you can post longer messages this way? And if you can post arbitrarily long messages in chat anyway if you know this, why restrict the chat message length at all?

Comment: @MadSci as you must know, that "how the hell" question holds for many, many features in SE, sadly. I'm not aware of what's happening behind the scenes (there could be a good/better reason markdown doesn't render) but I've always seen length limits on chat messages which could be worked around easily. SE is no exception.

Answer (score 4):

For comparison, this is the maximum length of a chat message:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
>   nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
>   sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
>   rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
>   ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
>   sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
>   dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
>   et justo duo dolores et

Comment: Isn't that good enough to convey the message? If one needs more he/she can send another chat msg rt? Am I missing something

Comment: @HackerKarma It's long enough for most messages, but you can hit the limit without being extremely verbose. The annoying thing about multiple messages is that another message can get in-between, splitting up the messages that belong together. It's not a huge deal, but it can be annoying

Comment: thanks Mad Scientist, in my question I have posted a message that regularly people use and my reasoning.

Comment: Thanks. I hardly use chat and when I do I always thought of small messages. But, I do see your and other use case where it could be annoying.

Comment: Multi-line (as in 'has embedded line feeds') can be much, much longer.