# Markdown in multiline messages does get rendered when starred

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, chat-stars

[We all know](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70141/201409) that multiline messages in chat don't support Markdown (except for fixed-width and quote formatting). But if such a message gets starred the Markdown will be rendered after all:

[image]

That is probably usually not a big deal, but I thought it's worth documenting (and very occasionally, a multiline message might rely on Markdown *not* working such that it becomes unreadable when starred).

Comment: Makes sense though, since there's no "multi-line" on the star board.