# Links posted as code become actual links when starred

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

When one posts a link in chat which is preceded by four spaces, it is formatted as code and isn't displayed as a link. [Example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32248958#32248958).

However, when starred, in the star wall it appears as an ordinary link:

> [image]

Can this please be fixed so that the star wall won't show it as a link?

Note: trying to precede internal Stack Exchange links with four spaces results in onebox, but [this is reported as a separate bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273158/oneboxing-has-suddenly-become-too-eager-aka-oneboxing-links-formatted-as-code).

Comment: [No repro](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xxlzg.png). Please give some example, with link to transcript. Also might be something on your end, please add what browser you're using, OS, etc.

Comment: @ShadowWizard let me get some screenshots. We were talking about this in AU chat. I can tell you I use Chrome on Windows, while Panda (I believe) uses FF on Ubuntu.

Comment: @ShadowWizard so it's not with backticks, it's with using 4 spaces. Backticks are formatted correctly: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hE6k0.png. The top two are using 4 spaces and the bottom two are using backticks.

Comment: @Zacharee1 thanks, I've embedded it into the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh, thanks. I was going to suggest an edit, but I wasn't sure if I would be changing the report too much.

Comment: @Zacharee1: It would have been closed otherwise.

Comment: @NathanTuggy well now I know a little bit more about how far I can go with editing on MetaSE. I'll try to put that knowledge to use ;)

Comment: @Zacharee1 what Nathan said. When a bug report is lacking vital information, or reported in wrong way, fixing it comes first, even if it means rewording it. (I mean fixing the way it is reported, lol)

Comment: Sorry, I was going to add a screenshot as an example, however I had to go somewhere and nobody was in the chat room to star my message.

Comment: Very similar: [Markdown in multiline messages does get rendered when starred](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270690/markdown-in-multiline-messages-does-get-rendered-when-starred)