# Syntax for chat messages?

Tags: support, chat, markdown

Chat messages do not seem to support markdown like questions and answer on SX.com websites - at least not fully. Where can I find the full syntax supported in chatroom messages?

Comment: @AnneDaunted: You would think so, but then - somehow linkification [doesn't always work](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46505512#46505512).

Comment: @einpoklum yeah, line breaks break chat formatting. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70141/398063).

Comment: No Markdown is processed for multi-line messages.

Comment: See the [chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting) section on formatting.

Comment: @Jenayah: At the link you gave, there's a multi-line message with a link just like mine. So - the FAQ is kind of misleading, isn't it?

Comment: iBug: But the FAQ example _is_ a multiline message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For chat markdown, click on the `help` button located at the bottom of every chat room. It seems to be a more complete version than included in the [faq#formatting link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting).