# Why wasn't this link in the chat made clickable?

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54730117#54730117:

[image]

Why wasn't this link in the chat made clickable?

Comment: Unfortunately, this was the way the chat system was designed; see [Markdown in chat fails for multi-line messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70141/markdown-in-chat-fails-for-multi-line-messages). There've been a ton of bugs filed since then, all of which have been closed as duplicates of that initial report marked by design; sadly, no one has made a new, substantiated request asking for it to be changed.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog "one has made a new, substantiated request asking for it to be changed." -> well I've just made a substantiated request asking to fix a bug :)

Comment: As the linked post says, this is not a bug. Any message with line breaks in it is parsed as plain text. The report is marked as "by design". The best thing one can do to change it is to make a feature request asking to change the design.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog thanks, good point I had missed it. I guess my ability to parse text is as bad as the chat's.