# Debugging links that don't display correctly in chat (without making a big mess)

Tags: support, chat, hyperlinks

In [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour)'s Agora chat room [I posted this text](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64944210#64944210) and the display was unsatisfactory because the links didn't show nicely.

I expected something like this (except with text dashes instead of the markdown bullets shown here - this is the actual pasted text)

- [Amnesty and Section Three of the Fourteenth Amendment](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/221946/02%20Magliocca.pdf)
- [S.J.Res.23 - A joint resolution to restore posthumously full rights of citizenship to General R. E. Lee.](https://www.congress.gov/bill/94th-congress/senate-joint-resolution/23/text?s=1&r=9)
- [S.J.Res.16 - A joint resolution to restore posthumously full rights of citizenship to Jefferson F. Davis.](https://www.congress.gov/bill/95th-congress/senate-joint-resolution/16/text?s=1&r=9)

but I got this:

[image]

I'm showing several messages together, the three lines with links were posted by themselves in a single message.

The `(removed)` indicates where I tried again without the `-` space-dash-space prefixes, but that didn't help.

How can I debug this situation - figure out why my links don't display properly by trial-and-error without making a mess in Agora or any other chat room?

"bonus points" for anyone who happens to know why this didn't display as I'd hoped/expected.

Comment: could always create a new 'sandbox' room for testing these things, if there isn't a standard one, but practically I suspect the answer is "chat is a little wierd about multiline posts"

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox

Comment: What the puppy said. Normal Markdown is disabled in Multiline posts. That's to prevent code blocks (which should be posted in Multiline mode) from getting mangled.

Comment: @PM2Ring this question is not about markdown. I have explained above that I tried again without the dashes and there was no change. Thanks for letting me know about the sandbox; cf. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64944378#64944378

Comment: A multiline message posts without most markdown being enabled.

Comment: @VLAZ **NO** because it still doesn't work even without markdown, unless any text containing more than one line is considered "markdown".

Comment: It's a markdown link. In a multiline message. That's how it's currently supposed to (not) work - the markdown links are not rendered. I don't understand what you mean by "even without markdown" - without markdown you won't have formatted links, just a URL.

Comment: "*unless any text containing more than one line is considered "markdown"*" any text of more than one line is considered *multiline*. The syntax `[link text](https://website.goes/here)` is markdown that is supposed to give you a hyperlinked "link text" which leads to `https://website.goes/here`

Comment: @VLAZ I've now answered my question based on comments, including your proposed dupe. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I debug this situation - figure out why my links don't display properly by trial-and-error without making a mess in Agora or any other chat room?

@PM2Ring [points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395898/debugging-links-that-dont-display-correctly-in-chat-without-making-a-big-mess?noredirect=1#comment1324244_395898) to

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox

which is exactly what I need.

> "bonus points" for anyone who happens to know why this didn't display as I'd hoped/expected.

- [We now support multi-line quotes in chat, but the rest of markdown is still disabled for multi-line messages.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192901/303080)

Also see [@VLAZ's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395898/debugging-links-that-dont-display-correctly-in-chat-without-making-a-big-mess/395902#comment1324254_395898):

> The syntax `[link text](https://website.goes/here)` **is markdown** that is supposed to give you a hyperlinked "link text" which leads to `https://website.goes/here`

Apparently what I want to paste, whether it contains the space-dash-space or not, as long as it's got some links and some line breaks, is, for the purposes of this situation, considered an unsupported construction of markdown, and so the answer to the "bonus points" questions is **this is not supported in chat**.